# Error messages when converting access 2000 to access 97

Tags: ms-access-2003, ms-access-2000, ms-access-97

When using access 2003 to convert an access 2000 database to access 97 I get the following 2 error messages right after the other

'invalid argument'

'Some errors happened during the conversion. No converted database was generated.'

Other than this there is no information provided.
Has anyone come across this before and have any clues about how to find the error
I compacted/repaired the database but this had no effect.

Comment: access '97? why?.... WHY?   I'm gonna crawl into a corner and just cry...

Comment: Did you try http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/194568-access-2002-conversion-back-access-1997-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because on conversion the size of the Access 97 database would have exceeded 1 GB which is the limit for that version of Access.